# PostgreSQL utf8 character comparison

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql, collation

I am changing from MySQL to PostgreSQL but can't find equivalent to MySQL's collation `utf8_general_ci`. What I'm trying to achieve here is to be able to compare strings using general language rules rather then binary comparison, i.e. í = i, š = s, ḩ = h, etc...

Is there a way how to make PostgreSQL search for strings using general language rules?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/charset.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, basically, what most modern `postgresql` installations will do for you by default. But you may also be interested in `initdb` options `--locale`, `--lc-collate`, etc. (most of those, if not all can also be changed after the database is initialized using .conf file).

You can also specify encoding and IIRC `LC_COLLATE` and friends when creating database.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also advice me on what locale can be used as a general one?

Comment: Whichever. I'm using `en_US.utf8`. I take it unicode collation doesn't depend on locale.